# Updates on a specific table in a database via Informatica takes a long time at a specific time interval

Tags: sql-server, informatica-powercenter

I am an informatica developer.

I have a dimension table in a Shared application database(SQL Server).
I have 4 keys on the table, and have a unique nonclustered index on this table.
At informatica target, we have the same 4 columns set as key columns.
We do a lookup on this dimension table on the same 4 keys to flag whether its an insert or an update.

I have a schedule in informatica where this job runs 6 times in a day at different intervals. For all the morning loads, the job run so quick, the throughtput of updates is like 1000 rec/sec.

But only for the evening load, for this particular table, the throughtput reduces like 12-15 rec/sec, this has started since last one month.

We expected that, there could be something else locking this table, or something at the database end. So contacted the DBA's they enabled a trace on this particular table, But they were not able to identity anything else. If anyone could assist me in any ways, or any hints where i might see, it would really be great.

The informatica server is also a shared server. But at this point of time where there is performance issue, both the SQL Server and the Informatica server are lightly loaded. If i have missed anything, kindly let me know and i can try to put additional information. The table has 94 columns, and The definition of the table goes as below, with A SurrogateKey, B,C,D and E being the keys :

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP(
A [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
B [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
C [varchar](11) NOT NULL,
D [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
E [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
F [varchar](1) NULL,
.
.
.
CP [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T_TEMP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [A] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_T_TEMP] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [A] ASC,
    [B] ASC,
    [C] ASC,
    [D] ASC,
    [E] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

All the columns are getting updated based on the 4 keys. So the update statement looks like below.

```
UPDATE TEMP
SET
F=?, 
G=?, 
H=?,
..
..
..
CP=?
WHERE B=? AND C=? AND D=? AND E=?;
```

Comment: We need something to here to be able to help. All we have is a description of the issue. We need details like the table definitions, the query you are running. etc.

Comment: Dear @SeanLange, Thanks for the reply, the table consists on 94 columns, definition below :

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50991651/edit) your question and put this information in the question. Comments are horrific for formatting.

Comment: Sorry let me add it in the question.

Comment: Dear @SeanLange, Please have a look, and let me know if i have missed anything else, i could provide more information, anything that could assist on the performance issue.

Comment: You don't have a covering index from the table structure you posted here. Your update is looking for column B, C, D and E but your unique index includes A. And there are NOT 4 keys here. You have a unique index and you are only addressing 4 of the 5 columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173644/discussion-between-raghav-rao-and-sean-lange).

Comment: Could be the load on the database, network bandwidth available / utilised at that time. Throttled network devices at times.

Comment: I'd need to see the session log for this...